# ORA-01008:not all variables bound in counting

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query gives me error

> ORA-01008:not all variables bound

```
select distinct salary
from emp1 a
where &n = (select count(distinct salary) from emp1 b
            where a.salary >= b.salary)
```

Comment: Do you provide a variable value for `n`?  what is you reverse the `where` caluse (`WHERE (...) = &n`)?

Comment: You are running this in what environment? `&n` is a SQL Plus substitution string, not a bind variable.